# Multiple Projects in VisualStudio 2012 in one Solution using GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am looking for a Solution having multiple Projects in one Solution, using one GIT repository per Project.

I want to be able to have multiple projects in one solution but each project has it's own GIT repo.

Lets say I got these project structure :

```
Solution Project 
- Some Client
- Some Other Project
- Some Lib Project that is used by all projects in this solution
- Some ASP Website
```

Any Thoughts how I can bring it to work ? Is Visual Studio 2013 able to handle this ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, in VS2013, one Team Solution equals one Git repo, and it's not obvious how I can import multiple Git repos into a single project/solution. I've asked some of the devs to chime in here, hopefully they can find the time.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment the Visual Studio integration only really handles a single repo containing the entire solution (and projects). Doesn't really work well when each project is in it's own repository or if you are using sub-modules etc.

Probably worth heading over to [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/) and adding your support for this, however I do know that it's something the team are looking at solving at some point

In the meantime, you are probably going to need to fall back to the command line I'm afraid.

Comment: Here are the existing UserVoice Q's I could find on the subject:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3729560-allow-multiple-repositories-in-a-team-project (0 votes)

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5367806-allow-multiple-git-or-tfvc-repositories-in-a-singl (9 votes) 

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4181074-enable-the-git-gui-in-visual-studio-to-clone-and-f (25 votes)

Comment: maybe this one :)  (526 votes) http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3606383-add-submodule-support-in-visual-studio-git-extensi

Answer (score 4):

It does not seem to be possible at this time (even in Visual Studio 2013).  Visual Studio handles one GIT repository per solution (including projects).

In order to be efficient, the best alternative I found is to use an application like SourceTree and include all your projects in it.

You can [Download SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/).

I found that using a software like SourceTree (or another) makes it simple to see which files were modified and what specific lines where edited.  It used to be a pain, in Visual Studio, to easily see what was modified in each file that were edited.

I mix this technique with the command line which I love.  But, I understand how great it would be to have everything in the same window.